# Sql server update auto incremental

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

tengo una tabla_x con 100 registros
Tengo que actualizar los datos de toda una columna_3 por registros incrementales empezando en 10000 hasta 10099

Como puedo hacer esta actualización sin afectar la estructura de la tabla

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar row_number() para lograr lo que buscas. Esta es una pregunta similar con algunas soluciones válidas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648898/sql-update-with-row-number